# Python socket seems to be getting overloaded. What are some ways to fix this?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am making a multiplayer game, although this could be applied to different types of applications, using udp sockets.

My server is sending the clients a message 60 times per second, since that is the framerate cap I have set. The problem happens when a client is running slower than 60 fps. When this happens, the messages are added to the queue and then therefore processed after they should have already happened. It makes it seem like I'm playing TPP! :P

The only fix I can think of, besides lowering the default fps, is to clear the queue every frame. I'm doing this currently like this:

```
self.socket.setblocking(0)
msg = ""
try:
    while True:
        msg = self.socket.recvfrom(1024)[0]
except:
    pass
finally:
    # Will handle msg here
    pass
```

Now this does work because it will just keep getting as many messages as it can until there are no more and then just use the last one that was recieved. I'm just wondering if this is a good way of doing it or if there is a better way of handling this problem.

EDIT: I have ended up sticking with this as it seems to work well and from looking at other Python source I have noticed that the trend is that having exceptions is an ok way to do things. I've always just learned programming that you should never have exceptions while programming if you have the power to control it.

I would really like some feedback though to set me on the right path.

Comment: Find a way to do network IO more often than drawing to the screen

Comment: You think maybe have a separate process? That might get confusing with different platforms but it's doable I suppose.

Comment: Not sure how your current program is laid out, but if you're limiting the main loop to run at most 60 times per second, maybe you can impose that limitation _only_ on the drawing part.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Thanks a lot. I just need to figure out how to do that because right now I'm using Pygame and its clock.tick function which basically just blocks for the period of time.

Comment: I could possibly use the time.set_timer to create an event every 16.6 milliseconds to draw